# Excel: Search and mark substrings in a column without writing a macro

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a column **A** and a column **B** in an Excel sheet.  Now I want to mark all cells in column A, which consists of values of column B (also **substrings**). E.g. A1 = "Programm" and B1 = "Prog". So in this case A1 should get a marker. Is this possible without a macro?

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional formatting on column A with a formula. For example for cell A1 the formula would be:

```
=(ISERROR(FIND(B1,A1))=FALSE)
```